# scikit-optimize gp_minimize - integer search dimensions?

Tags: scikit-optimize

The code

```
def objective(x, x_int=5):
    return x_int + sum(x)

# Use gp_minimize to find the minimum of the objective function
dims = [(0., 20.)]
res = gp_minimize(objective, dimensions=dims)

# Print the best set of parameters
print(f"Best set of parameters: {res.x}")
```

works but the code

```
def objective(x, x_int=5):
    return x_int + sum(x)

# Use gp_minimize to find the minimum of the objective function
dims = [(0, 20)]
res = gp_minimize(objective, dimensions=dims)

# Print the best set of parameters
print(f"Best set of parameters: {res.x}")
```

gives the following error

```
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'int'.
`np.int` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `int`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `int` by itself.
```

How can I create an optimizer for integer values?

The Bing chatbot suggests that I could downgrade my version of numpy to a version less than 1.24.  It's true that I am on Numpy version 1.26.3.  Do I need to downgrade to fix this?

Comment: See also this issue: https://github.com/scikit-optimize/scikit-optimize/issues/1138

Comment: @Nick ODell, yes, `np.int = int` fixes the issue.  Thank you!  If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I'd rather not write an answer when there's a better one elsewhere. If you click the button saying the duplicate answered your question, then it'll mark this Q as a duplicate, so that future searchers get steered toward that question when they have this problem.